# Create a seperate OCunit test project in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, unit-testing

If i want to do unit testing for my existing project i am adding a test target to the existing project and writing test case with in the available project. I dont want to submit the app with test classes to the appstore. Is there any way i can create a separate project for unit testing and it links to the original project by giving the path. So that i have two separate codes

1) original project code

2) Unit test code.

Please let me know how can i achieve it.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test classes are only compiled in your test target, so you do not need to create a separate project for testing because when you archive you are only building your application target, not the test one.

Comment: Is there any way to have two different codes or it is not possible?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with two different codes. Test specific code in your app target?

Comment: Test code separately from main project. Like in android they use separate JUnit project to test .

Comment: You do not need to do that in iOS. If you have an application target, you have a test target where you have your test clases (and maybe some test resources), no need for a test project. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: I wanted to use separate places to store the code for version/source control. I thought of sharing only the test project/code to a certain team while keeping the main project in a separate system since the size of the main project is very large. Is it possible?